# Ubuntu very slow - mono command

Tags: mono

I have Ubuntu 20.04 and very often it is very slow. Using TOP during these slow times I notice command "mono" is taking 80%-100% of the CPU. What is the mono command, do I need it, and how do I get rid of it?

Matt

Comment: When did you install mono? Mono is a cross platform open source framework for .NET apps (cross platform but usually associated with Microsoft/Windows) Apps using mono often weren't written with Linux in mind and are "ported" to run on Ubuntu. AFAIK, there are no versions of Ubuntu that come with mono installed by default, so this would have been something you installed- probably as a dependency for another application. Mono can be extremely **heavy** in terms of resource usage due to the fact that many applications use it because they weren't originally written to run on Linux natively

Comment: Try to retrace your steps and evaluate your user-installed software to determine which application is using mono.  That would be the application(s) that are eating into your resource usage.  Consider replacing that application with something that runs on Linux natively without mono

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I did not intentionally install mono. I installed Ubuntu 20.04 about 2 months ago and shortly after noticed the slowness. I'll have to retrace to find the offending software. Thanks again!

Comment: Any advice on how to find the installed application that uses mono?

Comment: What software have you installed that didn't come with Ubuntu?

Comment: Nmath, thats a good question. I installed Ubuntu 20 back in July and I'm trying to remember the additional stuff I installed. I understand I might be able to find this info in the "/var/log/dpkg.log" log files so I'm going to check there. Thanks!